# Find string between and replace with PHP

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I want to find and replace the string between the 2 sets of {{}}:

```
<p>I want to {{find}} this {{string}}.</p>
```

After I want to remove the {{}} and put the 2 strings in bold.

This is what I have tried:

```
$string = '<p>I want to {{find}} this {{string}}.</p>';
if(preg_match_all('/{{(.*?)}}/', $string, $matches) == 1) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        echo '<b>'.$match.'</b>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `preg_replace` like this

```
$string = '<p>I want to {{find}} this {{string}}.</p>';
$replaced_string = preg_replace('/{{(.*?)}}/', '<b>$1</b>', $string);
echo $replaced_string;
```

**Output**

I want to **find** this **string**.